# quick combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**A travelling salesemen is to visit any 5 different cities from a list of 10.**

**How many different itineraries he can have if he visits the cities successively one after another**

Update: the way I worded the question is exactly how it was in the textbook! so the ambiguity is not my fault!

Comment: i got 30240 but there was no solution so i do not know if i am correct

Comment: What do you mean by "successively one after another"?

Comment: The result
$$
{10 \choose 5} \cdot 5! = 30~240
$$
looks correct to me.

Comment: I understand the right hand side i.e. 30240 but I do not understand your left hand side @matti

Comment: my workings is 10P5 = 10!/(10-5)! = 30240

Comment: @Matti P.
What is the parenthesis thing * 5!?
I thought that paratnthesis thing means 10!/(10-5)!? so why times by 5!? wouldnt that get 151200?

Comment: @aperson, $n\choose k$ is a standard notation for binomial coefficients. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient . You'll almost encounter it sooner or later.

Comment: There are $10$ cities to start with, $9$ cities to choose as the second, ..., $6$ cities to choose as the fifth, so in total you have $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6$ possible choices. Another approch ist to first choose $5$ of the $10$ cities ($\binom{10}{5}$ ways to do so) and then give them a specific order ($5!$ ways). Of course, both yield the same result.